# Do java programmers need to deallocate memory for jni object

Tags: java, java-native-interface, free

There is a class using JNI. Some code like below

```java
public class JniUser {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public native int getAge();
    public native String getName();
}
```

In native code, set name and age fields. As far as I know Garbage collector will collect no referenced java objects. But in even in this case, GC can detect this object is target of GC or not?

I question about this since String is referenced type but not allocated by VM.

Should I free memory manually?

P.S. I know using JNI to implement VO is weird.

Comment: By `String`, do you mean `java.lang.String` or not?

Comment: Impossible to anwserwithout seeing the JNI code concerned.

Comment: Unless the native methods go out of their way to do the non-obvious thing, it all results with the fields holding references to JVM objects, just as they would in a normal java class.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the Java-wrapper object for the native object is garbage-collected as usual, however native code must do its own memory management. Let's use the OpenCV library as an example, because I'm familiar with it:

OpenCV has `Mat` objects which usually represents an image loaded into memory (but that is irrelevant for this example). A `Mat` objects holds its image data in native memory, but it also has a wrapper object in Java-memory so-that Java code can interact with it. The Java-wrapper is garbage-collected as soon as it goes out of scope, but for the native memory to be freed, the programmer needs to explicitly call `mat.release()`. This, however, introduces all manual memory management bugs back into Java:

- Memory leak if you forget to call `mat.release()`
- Use-after-free if you call `mat.release() and then attempt to do something with it again

So, with my limited experience, I would say that the native code needs to offer a method that frees the native memory (c.f. `Mat.release()`) and Java code needs to call that method explicitly.